# Error: Anonymous function expected when using a static function in PHP

Tags: php

Having some trouble with PHP static functions in my program. My code is below and I keep getting the error **"Anonymous function expected"**. I'm using the IDE PhpStorm.

I've had a google but nothing comes up. If I remove the name of the function the error goes away but I don't know how to then call the function.

```
<?php

/**
 * @param mysqli $conn Connection to the database.
 * @param int $id The ID of the white card that is to be voted up.
 */
public static function voteUp($conn, $id){
    mysqli_query($conn, 'UPDATE WhiteCards SET Ups = Ups + 1 WHERE ID = ' . $id);
}

/**
 * @param mysqli $conn Connection to the database.
 * @param int $id The ID of the white card that is to be voted down.
 */
public static function voteDown($conn, $id){
    mysqli_query($conn, 'UPDATE WhiteCards SET Ups = Ups - 1 WHERE ID = ' . $id);
}
```

Comment: how you call these function .?

Comment: @scaisEdge OP: *"but I don't know how to then call the function"* ;-) so it's anyone's guess.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   thanks  ..  I had not read properly  .. but what for If "I remove the name of the function the error goes away "

Comment: `public` suggests the use of a class; you also want to know how to call the functions; this question is both unclear and too broad. Best you go back to reading all the relevant manuals.

Comment: @scaisEdge again; anybody's guess, too many unknowns as per ^

Comment: @Fred-ii-   .. yes ..

Comment: @scaisEdge It'd be nice if we were to win a prize by successfully *guessing* `(?)`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  right .. if it were a crime would be the butler ... but ..for a function ... who knows who knows ... the fact that the function can be anonymous deepens the mystery

Answer (score 3):

Just solved it, the two functions needed to be in a class.